# How to Scape , (comma character) in csv file?

Tags: csv

For example if someone wants to scape ',' character, suppose your test.csv file is below

```
key,eng,gr
chose,Choose your preferred means of transport (Car, Bus, Train),Wählen Sie Ihr bevorzugtes Transportmittel (Auto, Bus, Bahn)
```

Car and Bus became part of column. I want it as a string

Comment: I think it's a matter of agreement between sender and receiver. CSV is an open format. You can agree on a different separator: `chose§Choose..(Car,Bus..)§Wählen..`  or you can escape in some way, example `(Car","Bus","Train),` as per [example here](https://learncsv.com/escape-characters)

Comment: this is a wrong CSV, it is not usable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should have double quotes for cells that have commas inside.

It should be in this way:

```
key,eng,gr
chose,"Choose your preferred means of transport (Car, Bus, Train)","Wählen Sie Ihr bevorzugtes Transportmittel (Auto, Bus, Bahn)"
```

If the problem is always inside `()`, you could use sed to remove the commas inside `()` and the comma at the end of line:

```
sed -r ':a;s/\(([^()]*),([^()]*)\)/(\1-\2)/g;ta;s/- */-/g;s/,$//'
```

to get

```
key,eng,gr
chose,Choose your preferred means of transport (Car-Bus-Train),Wählen Sie Ihr bevorzugtes Transportmittel (Auto-Bus-Bahn)
```

In this way you can parse the content of it because it's a right CSV